# Unable to skip the desired data from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have 3 `session_id`s from an array. I'm trying to check them one by one if they already exist in the database or not. Then skip the already exist ones and add the other `session_id`s to the database.

PHP Script:

```
foreach($json['sessions'] as $data)
{
            
    //Check if the same session is already exists in database
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM sessions WHERE session_id = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $data['session_id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    //If the session is not already exist, add it
    if (!$stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        $stmt->close();
        $a_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO sessions (session_id) VALUES (?)"); 
        $a_stmt->bind_param('s', $data['session_id']);
        $rc = $a_stmt->execute();
    }
    else {
        exit ('Already exists')
    }
}
```

It adds all the three `session_id`s to the database if none of them already exists.  If all three are exist it skips all of them. But the issue is, if it finds one or two of them already exist in the database it skips all the other `session_id`s too.

Answer (score 0):

You're tackling this the wrong way. If the `session_id` should be unique, tell the database that, and let it handle the conflicts.

To do this, add a unique index to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE `StackOverflow`.`sessions` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `session_id_UNIQUE2` (`session_id`);
```

Now you don't need to check the table before inserting, so modify your code:

```
// IGNORE throws a warning instead of an error. We can handle this later
$a_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO sessions (session_id) VALUES (?)");

// store any duplicate session IDs, if required
$duplicateSessions = [];

foreach($json['sessions'] as $data)
{
    $a_stmt->bind_param('s', $data['session_id']);
    $rc = $a_stmt->execute();
    if ($rc === false) {
        throw new Exception($mysqli->error);
    }
    // Check if the session was inserted. If not, store the ID
    if ($mysqli->affected_rows === 0) {
        $duplicateSessions[] = $data['session_id'];
    }

}
// Handle the duplicates here
$dups = "Duplicates sessions: ".implode(",",$duplicateSessions);
exit($dups);
```